# 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.: C on VS

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am new to programming and not familiar with IDE and developmental tools. I wanted to use Visual Studio Code, so I installed c/c++ extension and code runner offered by VS. But I get 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Some of the similar questions were quite old and I wonder if there are any recent solutions.
I would really appreciate if anyone can send me suggest any tutorials or videos on how to solve this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [vs code configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) if this helps...also you can compile using vs code terminal but first confirm gcc using "gcc -v" command in vs code terminal...

Comment: [Get Started with C++ and Mingw-w64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). In the [Prerequisites](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites) section don't forget step 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using windows;
Most probably there's no compiler installed on your machine. If you want to use VSCode for C programming, you should install a C compliler and add it to path variable in windows.

But my suggestion is use a different IDE, like Visual Studio Commuity or DevC++.

If you want to use VSCode, you should download and install MinGW, Cygwin or any other compiler.

If you are using Mac, Try installing XCode and use VSCode or CodeBlocks.

Comment: Please don't recommend Dev-C++. It's old, outdated, unmaintained, and comes with an ancient version of GCC.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will look into Visual Studio Community.